# Issues with Serverless framework Github action when mixing Java and Nodejs lambdas

Tags: github-actions, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a serverless project that has a bunch of nodejs lambdas.It builds and deploys fine in github actions.

Lately I added one Java Lambda which needs to be built with gradlew wrapper. A gradle task 'gradle build` first builds and packages the java code which is then later picked up my the main 'serverless deploy' which obviously runs in a nodejs context.

my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    api (
        'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.1',
        'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j:1.0.1',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0',


    )
}


group = 'app.serverless'
version = 'todo'

description = """hello"""


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

task deploy(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'build') {
  commandLine 'serverless', 'deploy'
}

task(buildJson) {
  println "in task(buildJson).."  
  doLast {
    new File("$buildDir/build.json").newWriter().withWriter { w ->
      w << groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([distribution: relativePath(shadowJar.archivePath)])
    }
  }
}

shadowJar.finalizedBy(buildJson)
build.dependsOn shadowJar
```

In my github acton file I use the gradle features of github actions to do a 'gradle build' first... which seems to run fine, but I guess the resultant zip file that it builds is not available to the 'serverless deploy' that runs later (since gradle and nodejs probly run in too different containers under the hood or seomthing ?)

```
name: Deploy 

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  Dev-Deployment:
    name: dev deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    #url : https://todo.com
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@bd5760595778326ba7f1441bcf7e88b49de61a25 # v2.6.0
      with:
        arguments: build
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}    
    - run: npm ci #similar to npm install
    - name: Install Plugin and Deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@v3.2
      with: # need this custom piece for the roles per function plugin https://github.com/marketplace/actions/serverless#usage-with-serverless-plugins
        args: -c "serverless plugin install --name serverless-iam-roles-per-function && serverless deploy --stage dev" 
        entrypoint: /bin/sh
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```